# How to get lib arch is iOS arm64 or Simulator arm64

Tags: c++, ios, cmake, lib

I am compiling a c++ library using make, but I am not sure if the compiled lib is suitable for the iOS platform

lipo-info can only output arm64, but the iOS emulator is not sure

Are there any other commands or tips to help me determine this? Any answer would be appreciated